# Getting unknown key type ed25519-sk on Mac M2 Ventura

Tags: openssl, ssh-keygen, fido

When trying to generate a key using:

```bash
ssh-keygen -t ed25519-sk -C "my instance key"
```

I get the following error:

```
unknown key type ed25519-sk
```

Anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by installing these two libs:

```bash
brew install libfido2
brew install openssh
```

My old openssl version was 9.0 and now it's 9.51. you can check it with ssh -V

After that, I opened a new terminal tab and I was able to generate the key using:

```bash
ssh-keygen -t ed25519-sk -C "my ed25519-sk key"
```